# sort() and reverse() functions do not work

Tags: python, list, sorting

I was trying to test how the lists in python works according to a tutorial I was reading.
When I tried to use `list.sort()` or `list.reverse()`, the interpreter gives me `None`.

Please let me know how I can get a result from these two methods:

```
a = [66.25, 333, 333, 1, 1234.5]
print(a.sort())
print(a.reverse())
```

Answer (score 37):

`.sort()` and `.reverse()` change the list *in place* and return `None` See the [mutable sequence documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

> The `sort()` and `reverse()` methods modify the list in place for economy of space when sorting or reversing a large list. To remind you that they operate by side effect, they don’t return the sorted or reversed list.

Do this instead:

```
a.sort()
print(a)
a.reverse()
print(a)
```

or use the [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) and [`reversed()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) functions.

```
print(sorted(a))               # just sorted
print(list(reversed(a)))       # just reversed
print(a[::-1])                 # reversing by using a negative slice step
print(sorted(a, reverse=True)) # sorted *and* reversed
```

These methods return a *new* list and leave the original input list untouched.

Demo, in-place sorting and reversing:

```
>>> a = [66.25, 333, 333, 1, 1234.5]
>>> a.sort()
>>> print(a)
[1, 66.25, 333, 333, 1234.5]
>>> a.reverse()
>>> print(a)
[1234.5, 333, 333, 66.25, 1]
```

And creating new sorted and reversed lists:

```
>>> a = [66.25, 333, 333, 1, 1234.5]
>>> print(sorted(a))
[1, 66.25, 333, 333, 1234.5]
>>> print(list(reversed(a)))
[1234.5, 1, 333, 333, 66.25]
>>> print(a[::-1])
[1234.5, 1, 333, 333, 66.25]
>>> print(sorted(a, reverse=True))
[1234.5, 333, 333, 66.25, 1]
>>> a  # input list is untouched
[66.25, 333, 333, 1, 1234.5]
```

Comment: We should make this the canonical answer to all duplicates of this question

Answer (score 2):

A simple ascending sort is very easy, call the sorted() function. It returns a new sorted list:

```
>>> sorted([66.25, 333, 333, 1, 1234.5])
[1, 66.25, 333, 333, 1234.5]
```

sorted() accept a reverse parameter with a boolean value.

```
>>> sorted([66.25, 333, 333, 1, 1234.5], reverse=True)
[1234.5, 333, 333, 66.25, 1]
```

Comment: I needed the python 2.x answer, so this worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

For reference, you can see the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) specifically says:

> The sort() and reverse() methods modify the list in place for economy of space when sorting or reversing a large list. To remind you that they operate by side effect, they don’t return the sorted or reversed list.

Don't be afraid to read the manual!

Answer (score 0):

This methods operate in place.

This code works (python 3.x)

```
a = [66.25, 333, 333, 1, 1234.5]
a.sort()
print(a)
a.reverse()
print(a)

>>> 
[1, 66.25, 333, 333, 1234.5]
[1234.5, 333, 333, 66.25, 1]
```