# sort() won't work? Keep getting NoneType back

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've been working on a program that can read a file that with multiple names in it and I just need to make it so it sorts the names now.

Something like this:

1. Bob
2. Bill
3. Tim
4. Tom
5. Rich

Into a list like above but sorted! `PrList.sort()` is where I need help and it's in the main function.

```
    def readfile(filename):

        infile = open(filename, "r")  
        filetext = infile.read().splitlines()    
        infile.close() 
        return filetext

    def printlist(list):

        for i, item in enumerate(list):
            print(i, ': ', item, sep="")

    def linear_search(search, value):

        for i in range(len(search)):
            if search[i] == value:
                return i

    def main():

        filename = input('File name: ')
        print()
        read = readfile(file)   
        PrList = printlist(read)
        print()

        PrList.sort()

        while True:
            name = input('Enter the name a name: ')
            if name == 'quit':
                sys.exit()
            else:
                ls = linear_search(read, name)
                print('The position of', name, 'is: \nLinear search: ', ls)
                print()

    main()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lab10c.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python34\lab10c.py", line 36, in main
    PrList.sort()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Comment: You are sorting just fine. Where do you get `None` here? Perhaps you tried to print the output of the method? If so, see [sort() and reverse() functions do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16460616); the method is *supposed* to return `None`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Want me to add the exact error I get?

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is the error I get. `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sort'`

Comment: You are assigning the return value of the function printlist. But printlist only prints the names and does not return anything.

Comment: @MaxOwnz: see, you always need to add your full error message to your questions. The full traceback is always appreciated; that way people don't have to comb through *all* your code to find the error.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My bad. I'm kind of new. Sorry. XD

Comment: You'd [edit] your question to add extra info like that :-)

Comment: LMAO @MartijnPieters So should I delete it and add it to my question?

Comment: @MaxOwnz: your traceback doesn't match the error you reported earlier now.

Comment: I don't know why... its being weird...

Comment: Please read [mre]. Make sure that other people can **copy and paste the example, without changing anything**, and get the exact error described - which you should also **copy and paste**. The best way to make sure is to **try it yourself** before posting.

Answer (score 1):

PrList = printlist(read)

function printlist() return None as default,you just print out the list,instead ,you should return it.

Comment: Return `list` in the `printlist` function right? @ekvilibro

Comment: def printlist(list):

        for i, item in enumerate(list):
            print(i, ': ', item, sep="")
 return list #or return enumerate(list)

Comment: I did that but it just prints the exact same list even with `PrList(read).sort()` @ekvilibro

Comment: ok,after read carefully,there are many problem in your code,first,printlist(list),list is a syntax keyword,you could and should not use it as a parameter name,second,readfile(file),pass the 'filename' not 'file'. also 'file' is a keyword too

Comment: Don't worry I changed those a while ago in my actual code @ekvilibro

Comment: It doesn't for me... @ekvilibro